Raw gzip data contains non-ASCII characters
I am working with gzip raw data that contains non-ASCII characters that I am unable to decompress and decode.
I am getting the data from Firestore through the python client and the payload looks like:
{'lastSchemaUpdateReason': 'new-app',
 'lastSchemaUpdateAt': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2023, 10, 3, 18, 2, 38, 6000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'schema': '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03íZÝRë6\x10~\x15\x8f§\x971´\x07\x0eC¹é\x00iJ\x18\x08\x84\x7fÎ)\x17\x8aµN\x14lÉHr\x02\x9cá%:½ï+ö\


It's binary data, why would you expect it to only contain ASCII characters?

I see. Is there a way to convert the gzip compressed binary?

I can'r reproduce the problem. with open('filename.gz', 'rb') as f: data = f.read(); expanded = gzip.decompress(data); print(expanded.decode()[:100])

This assumes the original file was text before it was compressed. If not, just print expanded[:100] to see the first 100 bytes of the result.

Please post a [mre]

If my_string is not the name of a file, your open is going to fail.

my_string in the example above is the given string starting with '\x1f\x8b\x08\ that I'm trying to decode but am unable to

How are you getting the data in the first place? You need to show that in your question. It should never be a normal string. What you are showing has already been corrupted. You need to bring it in as a binary string.

I am getting the data from google Firestore python client. the rest of the payload is textual so I can't bring it in as anything else

Updated the post with the full payload @MarkAdler

That looks like JSON.  You're going to need a JSON decoder to pull out that part of the data as a binary byte string.

This with open(my_string,'rb') as f: makes no sense, you're using the "payload" as a file name? (hence the embedded null byte error) Where are you getting this data, and how? Please share more information about how you obtained the data and how you came up with the form that you shared formatted as a string in your example?

@MarkRansom When I run json.dumps on that part of the data I get a string that loses the gzip prefix: '"\\u001f\\u008b\\b\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0003\\u00edZ\\u00ddR\\u00eb6\\u0010~\\u0015\\u008f\\u00a7\\u00971\\u00b4\\u0007\\u000eC\\u00b9\\u00e9\\u0000iJ\\u0018\\b\\u0084\\u007f\\u00ce)\\u0017\\u008a\\u00b5N\\u0014l\\u00c9Hr\\u0002\\u009c\\u00e1%:\\u00bd\\u00ef+\\u00f6\\u0011*\\

@Grismar Thanks, yeah I realize that now regarding the open. I update the post with the original payload returned from the Firestore API python client. Specifically, I want to decode the schema which looks like it has a gzip prefix?

@MarkRansom Though JSON uses double quotes.

I attempted to convert that string to binary by converting the escapes (e.g. \x1f, \t) to bytes, and leaving the Unicode characters as their UTF-8 representation. However the resulting gzip stream was invalid. As far as I can tell, that gzip data was corrupted when it was encoded in that form. Possibly irretrievably so.

The gzip header is fine. But the first two characters of the compressed data, íZ with the first character encoded as UTF-8, immediately results in an error (distance too far back). Those two characters are three bytes in UTF-8: c3 ad 5a. No bueno.

I then tried two-byte unicode representations of the first three characters, in big and little-endian: 00 ed 5a 00 dd 52 and ed 00 5a dd 00 52. Both still no bueno.

It seems that 'schema' is not specified properly.
The value currently saved in 'schema' looks as if it was just dragged and pasted from the output of print(the gzipped binary data).
If 'schema' contains binary gzipped data, it works well.
$ cat kk.txt
This is dummy data to make dummy gzip bin
$ gzip -k kk.txt
$ ls
kk.txt
kk.txt.gz

import gzip
from pathlib import Path


data_gzipped = Path("kk.txt.gz").read_bytes()
data = {'lastSchemaUpdateReason': 'new-app', 'schema': data_gzipped}
print(data)
print(gzip.decompress(data.get("schema")))
# result
# {'lastSchemaUpdateReason': 'new-app', 'schema': b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xcd\xde\x8df\x00\x03kk.txt\x00\x0b\xc9\xc8,V\x00\xa2\x94\xd2\xdc\xdcJ\x85\x94\xc4\x92D\x85\x92|\x85\xdc\xc4\xecT\xa8PzUf\x81BRf\x1e\x17\x00\xa9\x12\xbd\x9c*\x00\x00\x00'}
# b'This is dummy data to make dummy gzip bin\n'

I recommend to check the code of assigning gzip data to schema variable.
